# Compare two values from consecutive rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data from a meter

| DrID | attPercentage | VID | IAPD | DeviceID | IsAggregate | PrID | Timestamp | monthTS | YearTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1366 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 49 | 0 | NULL | 2001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1 | 2001 |
| 34661090 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 49 | 0 | 1366 | 2001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1 | 2001 |
| 34661091 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 49 | 0 | 1366 | 2001-02-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 2 | 2001 |
| 34661092 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 49 | 0 | 1366 | 2001-03-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 3 | 2001 |
| 34661093 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 49 | 0 | 1366 | 2001-04-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 4 | 2001 |
| 34661094 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 49 | 0 | 1366 | 2001-05-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 5 | 2001 |
| 34661095 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 49 | 0 | 1366 | 2001-06-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 6 | 2001 |
| 34661096 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 49 | 0 | 1366 | 2001-07-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 7 | 2001 |
| 34661097 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 49 | 0 | 1366 | 2001-08-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 8 | 2001 |
| 34661098 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 49 | 0 | 1366 | 2001-09-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 9 | 2001 |
| 34661099 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 49 | 0 | 1366 | 2001-10-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 10 | 2001 |
| 34661100 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 49 | 0 | 1366 | 2001-11-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 11 | 2001 |
| 34661101 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 49 | 0 | 1366 | 2001-12-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 12 | 2001 |

Here the first row is Parent device and rows below its children. I want to make sure that all the children devices (which has PrID equal to the DrID) should have the same 'attPercentage' value as Parent device.

So here the DrID 34661095 would be the problem as it has 'attPecentage' value of 1 is different to its parents device (1st row) which has a 'attPecentage' value of 0

This is just a small sample from a huge dataset I have.

The expected output here would be the all child row which has the differnt value then parent.

For example in this case, the expected outcome should be row number 7 with DrID 34661095

Any guidance of how to do it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `lag`? We need to see what you have tried in order to help - otherwise we are just writing it for you.

Comment: Or `LEAD`? [LAG (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [LEAD (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: LEAD and LAG won't help here, since e.g. the third row is child of the first row, not of the second row which would be returned by LAG. I would suggest do get all parent IDs and their values via sub query of "PrID is NULL", then join it with all remaining rows on PrID and then compare the values...

Comment: Yes i came across lead and lag but it won't be useful here as my subsequent 12 rows is the child of 1st row. Even if I get the values of  all the ParentID where PrID is null. How how can I compare the two?

Comment: @DaleK I am very new at SQL. I am not looking for the exact code or something. A little guidance towards the right direction would be enough for me to attempt something worthwhile on my own

Comment: You should really normalize this out, parent and child rows in separate tables with foreign keys. And don't think you need `LAG` here, it's just a self-join `PrID = DrID`

Comment: But what is the expected output? only parent records where attPercentage matches with child or not matches? only parent record? all only parent - child which are not matching.

Comment: @Popeye the expected output would be parent-child which are not matching

Comment: Why don't you update the question with expected output? Do you need one row for parent and one row for child  or parent-child in single row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that through subquery. If DRID field is unique then below query will serve your purpose.

```
select DrID,
       attPercentage,
       VID,
       IAPD,
       DeviceID,
       IsAggregate,
       PrID,
       Timestamp,
       monthTS,
       YearTS
from tableName child
where PrID is not null
  and attPercentage <> (
                       select attPercentage
                       from tableName parent
                       where parent.DrID = child.PrID)
```

Comment: Why inside the case, attpercentage is null is being considered?

Comment: I have changed the query so that it doesn't try to fetch parent attpercentage when it's a parent row. Please elaborate how attpercentage being null can have impact so that i can rewrite the  query if needed. I didn't consider attpercentage being null.

Comment: The query is not giving me the output which is expected. 
The first row is the Parent row (as it has PrID = NULL) and all the subsequent 12 rows below are its children (as their PrID = DrID of first row). All the children attpercentage  values should be the same as Parent. Therefore the query should output any row where the value of attpercentage  does not matches the value of attpercentage for the parent.

Here Row 7  has attpercentage  = 1 which is different to its parentID (row 1) which has value = 0

Comment: Yes, ideally would want the query to perform such that row 7 with DrIF 34661095 comes as an output as it has attpercentage value different then that of its PrID (row 1)

Comment: Extremely sorry for the inconvenience. You clearly stated that but i missed. I have changed the query as you needed. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

One method is a `join`:

```
select t.*, t.attPercentage as parent_attPercentage
from t left join
     t tp
     on t.prid = tp.drid;
```

Another method -- assuming that all values are `0` or `NULL` in the child rows -- is to use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       max(t.attPercentage) over (partition by coalesce(t.prid, t.drid)) as parent_attPercentage
from t;
```

Comment: What is left join tp here? and does the t.id means t.DrID ?

Comment: @AyushSinghania . . . I fixed those typos.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  - I think the join in the first example should be t.prid = tp.drid? Also, I've been wondering.... if there are multiple layers of children, shouldn't we be thinking about a recursive solution?